USB became read-only after using dd to flash a Linux ISO
I recently used the dd command to flash a Linux ISO to my USB drive. After doing so, the USB drive has become read-only. I suspect that using dd might have caused this issue, as suggested in this answer to a similar question.
I was able to temporarily gain write access to the USB drive by following the steps outlined in this answer from the same question. However, the write access is lost every time I reboot my laptop, and the USB drive reverts to read-only mode.
Any help or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

"However, the write access is lost every time I reboot my laptop, and the USB drive reverts to read-only mode." – Does it remember the changes you made to the content? It's very likely the controller inside the USB drive considers the flash memory unreliable and is giving you a chance to read the data before the hardware dies completely, without giving you a chance to finish it off by writing.

Please tell the age of and estimated amount of use this device has seen.

Also, check how it's mounted. Auto mounting might make it RO unless you set it otherwise.
